# Not finding Unity Catalog "Create Metastore" in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I am trying to set up Unity Catalog in Azure Databricks following this documentation [Unity Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities#config-managed-id), but I do not find "Create Metastore" on Databricks. What do I need to do?

Comment: are you AAD global admin? Or you were promoted to Databricks Admin in account console?

Comment: @AlexOtt I was promoted. I thought I had sufficient Admin access, but do you think I need the owner to create the metastore?

Comment: Hmmm, strange that if you're account admin, then you should see it

Comment: The documentation is in a need of improvement around this, imo. There are four different administration roles for Databricks: _[Azure Owner/Contributor, Azure Databricks account admin (needed for Unity Catalog), workspace admins, AD Administrator]_ Personally I have the same problem as OP.

Comment: Agreed! The issue was resolved by getting the Owner to create the metastore and then promote us to Azure Databricks account admins.

Answer (score 0):

it is required that you will login as databricks admin.
To login as an administrator, it is necessary to have the role of global administrator
on the azure subscription, otherwise it will never appear