# Creating a metastore for Azure Databricks Unity Catalog through terraform fails

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Creating a metastore for Unity Catalog through terraform fails with this error message:

```bash
Error: cannot create metastore: Only account admin can create metastores. \ 
Using databricks-cli auth: host=https://{wsname}.azuredatabricks.net, \
token=***REDACTED***, profile=DEFAULT
```

My config is setup like this:

```
resource "databricks_metastore" "this" {
  name = "primary"
  storage_root = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    azurerm_storage_account.storage.name,
  azurerm_storage_container.container.name)
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "databricks_metastore_assignment" "this" {
  metastore_id = databricks_metastore.this.id
  workspace_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.oat.workspace_id
}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/) regarding Azure Databricks administrators lists up four different kinds of administrators, but I fail to see how I can see check who is Azure Databricks account admins.

In short, I have the same error as [Not finding Unity Catalog "Create Metastore" in Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73607469/6383431)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your account is a workspace admin. Account administrator is one level above.

This [Unity Catalog documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started#requirements) describes how you become account administrator:

> The first Azure Databricks account admin must be an Azure Active
> Directory Global Administrator at the time that they first log in to
> the Azure Databricks account console. Upon first login, that user
> becomes an Azure Databricks account admin and no longer needs the
> Azure Active Directory Global Administrator role to access the Azure
> Databricks account.

Thus, you need Global Administrator role in Azure for the user that is running Terraform.

Comment: That is a strange setup step, _or_ it is phrased in a way that is easily misunderstood. It sounds like if the Azure Databricks account is already setup by an non AAD Global role, it is not possible to create a Metastore?

Comment: Thanks man, the same permission is also needed indeed if you wanna create a Unit Catalog using Manage Account method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-metastore

Hope they change this soon...

Comment: I logged a feedback item for this, if you want to vote for it. Not sure who looks at those or how often though. https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/61f5bbe0-5160-ed11-a81b-000d3ae49307